# problem when I try to pass array of boolean by references on arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using `Arduino` and I want to pass a parameter by references 
so my parameter was an array of boolean, like this:

```
boolean isCodeHaveEnd(boolean (&code)) {
      boolean TCode[18] = { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,1
                          , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
                          , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0} ;
      boolean XCode[18] ;
      for (size_t i = 108; i < 125; i++) {
           XCode[i] = code[i] ;
      }
      return equal(TCode, XCode, 18) ;
 }
```

whatever I tried I face the same error

```
src/main.cpp:109:33: error: invalid types 'boolean {aka bool}[size_t {aka unsigned int}]' for array subscript

XCode[i] = code[i] ;
```

Comment: `code` is a reference to a single `boolean`.  You probably want to pass it by pointer, `boolean *code`, since it is an array.  Accessing `XCode[i]` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score -1):

problem solved, just need to add a const before the type of the parameter as follows:

```
boolean isCodeHaveEnd(const boolean (&code)[126]) {
      boolean TCode[18] = { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,1
                          , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
                          , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0} ;
      boolean XCode[18] ;
      for (size_t i = 108; i < 125; i++) {
           XCode[i] = code[i] ;
      }
      return equal(TCode, XCode, 18) ;
 }
```